# Spring Security Authorize by authentication method

Tags: spring, security, authentication, authorization

How can I limit the access to a method, base on the authentication method, in Sprint Security?

For example, I want two methods of authentication to my service: basic and LDAP. But for one method in my service I only want access to be allowed if the user authenticated using basic-authirization.

I know I can add `Authentication` to the method signature and then check if it's an instance of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, but that seems a but ugly and not really using the full power of the framework.

I guess I can do the same with `PreAuthorize`.

Another ugly way to do this is to add a rule to every authenticated user that tells the authentication method. I can the authorize base on the role. Again, ugly

But is there a more out-of-the-box/Springy way of doing this?

Comment: I think you shouldn't look at how user has authenticated, but to him having the necessary grants to access the resource. Then what about having a concrete role for this case? I think it would be a mistake to couple your business code to the authentication method logic.

Comment: A classic case would be JWT. As long as it's valid, you can use it to get everywhere. But I wouldn't want you to get a new JWT with an existing one. That would beat the idea of it expiring.

Comment: I don't think so. From my point of view, JWTs are evaluated in such a way that a resource server could grant it even without making any request to the authorization server. The token itself contains information about when it's going to expire and that's evaluated for the token individually. So a single user could retrieve as much tokens as he wants, as long as he provides valid credentials. The idea of expiring on the other hand, has more to do with a token being stolen. That way the attacker would be given little time to perform some action.

Comment: @xtreme biker, I can see you point of view, but this is still a requirement I need to implement. Obviously, I don't want to meddle with the security layer. I'm just looking for a way to query the authentication method from the service method.